# Drupal Module for Zoom Print and Save

Tags: views, 7

I would like to ask about finding a particular module on Drupal. I need to add "Zoom", "Print", and "Save" functionalities.

I am sure there must be a module to handle this. Is there any solution about which module I should use? For your information, I am using Drupal 7 and need to add the functionality to Views page.

Comment: You try this http://drupal.org/project/print ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by zoom!! Image zoom or text resize?

Anyways you need to install 3 modules

- for image zoom use [deepzoom](http://drupal.org/project/deepzoom)
- for text resize use [textsize](http://drupal.org/project/textsize)
- for print and save use [Printer, email and PDF versions](http://drupal.org/project/print)